# jQuery animation out of sync

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

Very shortly after my animation starts, it goes out of sync.
The divs are supposed to fade in and fade out after one another.

Please take a look at my code below...

Thanks

```
(document).ready(function(){ 
    animate_loop = function animate_loop(){
            $( "#w01" ).animate({ opacity: 0.4, }, 1000,
                function(){ $( "#w01").animate({ opacity: 1}, 600)
                animate_loop();
            } );    
    }
   animate_loop(); 

    animate_loop = function animate_loop(){
            $( "#w02" ).animate({ opacity: 0.4, }, 1500,
                function(){ $( "#w02").animate({ opacity: 1}, 600)
                animate_loop();
            } );    
    }
   animate_loop(); 

    animate_loop = function animate_loop(){
            $( "#w03" ).animate({ opacity: 0.4, }, 2000,
                function(){ $( "#w03").animate({ opacity: 1}, 600)
                animate_loop();
            } );    
    }
   animate_loop(); 

    animate_loop = function animate_loop(){
            $( "#w04" ).animate({ opacity: 0.4, }, 2500,
                function(){ $( "#w04").animate({ opacity: 1}, 600)
                animate_loop();
            } );    
    }
   animate_loop(); 
});
```

Comment: @miro What do you mean?

Comment: You are using the same function for different divs. It is calling the same function as soon as the second one is up. Why is eveything wrapped in document ready?

Comment: What is you HTML look like?

Comment: Yes, It is supposed to be calling the same function for another element as soon as the first one is over. @miro HTML is just nested divs one on top of the other using float...

Comment: @miro As for the document ready, I've changed it, I've warped the functions inside one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want more control use the code below. I highly recommend using adding a class and then animating trough CSS instead of making a jquery loop.

Here's a new demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mirohristov/gw8kskom/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#w01').delay(1000).queue(function(){
        $(this).addClass("go");
    });

    $('#w02').delay(1500).queue(function(){
        $(this).addClass("go");
    });

    $('#w03').delay(2000).queue(function(){
        $(this).addClass("go");
    });

    $('#w04').delay(2500).queue(function(){
        $(this).addClass("go");
    });
});
```

Comment: That looks great. Only problem is I'm not using a list, just divs. Tried the class .go on it's own in css and it didn't work. Am assuming it's because of that...

Comment: list has nothing to do with it. Just copy eveything from CSS of this fiddle and paste to your <style> or .css file
You're missing some fundamendal knowledge on css selectors: tags, classes, ids etc. Here's a tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7aeRypQgkTo

Comment: I have, take a look: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-JfRH1eM2WcRDIzSnVIQU91dUE/view?usp=sharing  still not working...

Comment: paste the whole documnet with the html in a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to just make a fade effect, use css and add a class at a different time with setInterval. Use `.each(index, el)` to iterrate trough each element. Index will be 1, 2, 3, 4, etc... so use that to delay your animation.

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mirohristov/gw8kskom/

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('.child').each(function(index, el){
        setTimeout(function(){
        $(el).addClass('go');
        }, 200*index);
    });
});
```

Comment: How do I adapt this with ID's and target each element specifically so I can have better control?